# highlight cells before specified date in column

Tags: excel, date, find, vba

I have a column of dates in the format MM/DD/YYYY and want to highlight specific ranges of these dates. For example, the first section of highlighted dates should be everything from the first row all the way up to the current friday. Sometimes that date is not in the sheet so I have a few extra lines that check if that date is not listed, it will check for the current thursday. When using the .find method of searching the column I am having issues and also am having issues saying I am using an end if without an if statement even though I am. Kind of confused on the errors I am getting.

```
Dim friday As Date
Dim rng As Range

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("A:A, C:C, H:H, J:J").Delete

friday = Date + 8 - Weekday(Date, vbFriday)

Columns("C:C").Select
Set rng = Selection.Find(What:=friday, After:=Range("C1"),
LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Select

    Else: friday = friday - 1

    End If
```

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting?

Comment: conditional formatting is a very good solution for this problem.
[This will help with conditional formatting](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2488-excel-conditional-format-date-less-greater-than-today.html)

Comment: This is a sheet that is downloaded from another program every week. So the idea is that the dates and thing change, you download a new sheet then run the macro. I didn't think I could get conditional formatting to work with a new sheet every time. I thought that would only work if I have this sheet saved and keep opening the same one.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do with the code. You're using `.Find` to look for `friday`, but then you don't seem to be doing anything after that. Also, avoid using `.Select` when possible. It's not necessary to select data to perform some action on it. This code will look at all the values in column A and highlight the dates equal to `friday`:

```
Sub test()

Dim friday As Date
Dim sht_data As Worksheet
Dim i, LastRow as long

Set sht_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data") 'change to your sheet name

friday = Date + 8 - Weekday(Date, vbFriday) 'get date for comparison

With sht_data
    LastRow = .Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row

    For i = 1 To LastRow 'assumes data starts in first row
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value = friday Then
            .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) 'highlight yellow
        Else: End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

You can play with that to highlight ranges of datas (i.e. update the If clause to check for a range).

Comment: I left out the rest of the code because it is not important to the issue I was having and I didn't want to crowd the post but I'll try this out and play with it a little to see if I can get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Context usually helps! I saw the `Columns.Delete` statement, then a `.Select` statement two lines after for the data you just deleted. It just didn't make sense =)

Comment: Sorry about that. But so far it seems to work! Just have to change a few things to fit my specific needs but I should be able to get it done. Thanks!